# BBcode parsing problem

Tags: bbcode

I use this function for BBcode parsing:

```
function bbcode ($message) {
$search = array(
'@\[(?i)b\](.*?)\[/(?i)b\]@si',
'@\[(?i)i\](.*?)\[/(?i)i\]@si',
'@\[(?i)u\](.*?)\[/(?i)u\]@si',
'@\[color=rgb(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color\]@si',
'@\[quote](.*?)\[\/quote\]@si',
'@\[li](.*?)\[\/li\]@si',
'@\[ul](.*?)\[\/ul\]@si',
);

$replace = array(
'<b>\\1</b>',
'<i>\\1</i>',
'<u>\\1</u>',
'<span style=\"color:rgb\\1\">\\2</span>',
'<span class=\"quote">\\1</span>',
'<li>\\1</li>',
'<ul>\\1</ul>',
);
return preg_replace($search , $replace, $message);
}
```

In most cases it works ok, but not always.

For example:

```
[color=rgb(102, 0, 102)]H[color=rgb(204, 0, 0)]e[/color]llo[/color]
```

The result is:

```
<span style="color:rgb(102, 0, 102)">H[color=rgb(204, 0, 0)]e</span>llo[/color]
```

As you can see, only the first **[color=...][/color]** has been converted to html. The second stays as it is. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want recursive structure like that, you'll have to use something a bit more complex than a plain `preg_replace`. Regexp doesn't handle hierarchy very well.

Comment: there are millions of free scripts on the net, but I spent days and can't find a good bbcode parser which works without problems :(

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly as you specified it. The problem is with embedded sequences.
I suggest you perform two replaces. One for the starting tags and one for the ending tags.
You might also be able to get away with specifying all of the starting tags first and
all of the ending tags last in the array of replacements.
That makes the search-replace values simpler anyway and in most cases you don't
need to use back-references, especially for simple tags like [b].
That should fix your problem.

Comment: And then some clueless user comes around and breaks your HTML by not closing their bbcode tags properly.

Comment: Matti Virkkunen, yes that's the problem! Some users may not close bbcode tags.